# comparing a return from strdup function, with strncmp

Tags: c, strcmp

I am new to `C` language. I am trying to compare two returned values from `strdup`, with the `strncmp` function, but getting following error:

> error: passing argument 2 of ‘strncmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

my code:

```
if (0 == strncmp( strdup(str_to_dup1), strdup(str_to_dup2)))
```

Comment: strncmp takes 3 arguments but you're only passing 2. Besides, it's not a good idea to compare the results of `strdup` as they could fail and return NULL.

Comment: Posting more of your code would generate more answers to the overall issue: comparing strings.

Answer (score 2):

From [strncmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp)

> strncmp
>
> int strncmp( const char *lhs, const char *rhs, size_t count );

In you code, you are missing the third argument of `strncmp` which is the maximum number of character to compare.

Your program is having potential memory leak as the pointer returned by `strdup()` will be lost after `strncmp()` call. Also, you should be aware that `strdup()` can return `null` pointer if an error occurred.

You should take the `strdup()` returned pointer to a variable and make sure to check for if some error is occurred and then pass those variables to `strncmp()`. Once done with `strdup()` returned pointers, free them using `free()`.

Comment: Or just don't dup them at all. There's no reason not to pass the original strings to strncmp.

Answer (score 0):

strncmp takes 3 parameters  like below

```
int strncmp(const char *str1, const char *str2, size_t n)
```

in your code missing the third parameter, the max number characters to be compared